how can optimize a composition for a composable that takes in a list as input
I have a problem and need help understanding the terminology, so here is what I have:
I have a User composable that takes a User object as a parameter. It looks something like this:
@Composable
fun UserView(user: User) {
    // Rendering the view
}

Users are grouped under departments, so I have a composable called DepartmentView. The department takes a list of users as a parameter:
@Composable
fun DepartmentView(users: List<User>) {
    // Render
}

I also have a ViewModel that loads and pushes users into the main UI.
The problem: Each time a user is added, the entire department is recomposed, which means all the users inside the department are recomposed. This makes the loading appear laggy.
I'm trying to work around this to prevent the already added users from recomposing.

What are you using to show the list? If you are using a column or grid with a loop inside, it will definitely not perform well. You need to use a LazyColumn or LazyVerticalGrid with unique item keys.

hi @dev.tejasb , i have lazycolumn to show DepartmentView list , but when i try to add another lzaycolumn inside each DepartmentView  , it doesn't work , it seems that i can't do inner lazycolumn , if yoiu have info about that please help

what do you mean by it doesn't work? and are you using keys?

the app crashes unless i use height , i guess the lazycolumn need a height spesified becuase it need to know what's visisble and what's not

can you post the relevant code?

you can't add a nested vertical scroll in compose like LazyColumn inside another lazy column if you design requirement allow you can include child lazyRow inside lazycolumn or use vertical or horizontal scroll modifiers
